# How to overrider Logger class with method to select log level and output line of the log

Tags: python, django, logging

I need to record logs in many places of my Django application and I want to have it in a standardized way so that when people contribute they don't have to worry to much about it.

So instead of calling:

```
logger.info(<standardized message here>)
```

I would like to write a function or probably a class that inherits `Logger` and selects the correct `.info`, `.warning`, `.error` and so on and outputs the message the way we want.

So in the code I would only call

```py
log(request, 200, "info", "Success message")
```

And the function I wrote looks like this:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def log(request=None, status_code=None, level=None, message=None):
    """
    Create a log stream in a standardized format
    <request_path> <request_method> <status_code>: user <user_id> <message>
    """
    method = request.method
    path = request.path

    user_id = None
    if not request.user.is_anonymous:
        user_id = request.user.id

    log = f"{path} {method} {status_code}: user {user_id} {message}"

    if level == 'info':
        logger_type = logger.info
    elif level == 'warning':
        logger_type = logger.warning
    elif level == 'error':
        logger_type = logger.error
    elif level == 'debug':
        logger_type = logger.debug

    return logger_type(log)
```

The problem is that our log formatter also records the line in the code where the log happened, and because the log is called in the `log` function, the row reflects the `return logger_type(log)` instead of the actual line in the code where `log` was called.

How can I write a class with a method to do the automatic selection of log level based on the input and still stream the log from the line where it happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to stick with your helper function approach, the logging methods accept kwarg `stacklevel` that specifies the corresponding number of stack frames to skip when computing the line number and function name [ref](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug). The default is 1, so setting it to 2 should look to the frame above you helper function. For example:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(format="%(lineno)d")
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def log():
    logger.error("message", stacklevel=2)


log()
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to have it in a standardized way

If you really want to do things in a standardized way, then use what the `logging` module gives you and don't create your own helper functions.

The logging already lets you pass in "extra" arguments for the logging message ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug)):

```
logger.info("success message", extra={"request": request, "status_code": 200})
```

You can then put your logic extract parts of the request in a [formatter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#formatter-objects) object.

As well as following the standard, this will give you additional flexibility, as your formatter can do different things based on what extra parameters it gets.

One thing that the Python logging module is missing that other loggers have is the idea of a thread-local "context" object. You could use such and object to preserve the request at the time it's processed, so that it's available in all log messages without being passed in explicitly. You could implement this by adding a `request_context` dictionary to the current thread, and look for it in your formatter.

Comment: Re. thread-locals, `logging` can certainly use these - there's no need for the package to provide something just for its own use. You can just create a thread-local holding whatever information you need and then pass it in the `extra` argument.

Comment: @VinaySajip - take a look at the Log4J "mapped diagnostic context" to see what I'm talking about. The idea is that you provide contextual information at one place in your code (eg, the top of a request handler), and it's attached to all log messages. This is, imo, a much better idea than passing the same information to every log message.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of MDC/NDC in `log4j`. That's what I'm talking about too, except that you can set up any thread local and then set info in there for a request (e.g. client IP address). You can then use e.g. a filter to add that information into a log record and a suitable format string to output it. Here's a post I did about it in 2010: https://plumberjack.blogspot.com/2010/09/configuring-logging-for-web.html